# how to insert array to a field in db - wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I want to insert values to database each time when values are submitted.

These are the post values from the form.

```
$sFloorKey       = $_POST['floorname']; // int value : eg - 5
$aRoomName       = $_POST['roomname']; //array contaning multiple values
$iRoomType       = $_POST['roomtype']; //array contaning multiple values
$iPostID         = $_POST['postid']; // int value : eg - 44
```

The wp query performed ,

```
$wpdb->insert('bs_room_types', array(
                                   'postid'       => $iPostID ,
                                   'sfloorname'   => $sFloorKey,
                                   'aroomname'    => $aRoomName,
                                   'aroomtypes'   => $iRoomType, 
                                   ));
```

The `$sFloorKey` and `$iPostID` are getting inserted but the array values not.

Please help out here!

Comment: check your field type in your database table, probably you want a varchar

Comment: You need to `serialize()` them before inserting. Example: `serialize($aRoomName);`

Comment: @Roljhon ,  its varchar only .

Comment: @Chinou check the length and the suggestion of Milan above

Comment: @MilanChheda when i'm serializing and inserting, the whole insertion query is not working !

Comment: What error are you receiving? Hope you are doing `serialize($_POST['roomname']);` AND `serialize($_POST['roomtype']);`

Comment: @MilanChheda thank you :) its working now..unfortunately i have given less size for field in db.

Answer (score 0):

As per the help of @MilanChheda its working perfectly now.

Before inserting i have serialized the values.

```
$iPostID         = $_POST['postid'];
$sFloorKey       = $_POST['floorname'];
$aRooms          = serialize($_POST['roomname']);
$iRoomType       = serialize($_POST['roomtype']);

$wpdb->insert('bs_room_types', array(
                                   'postid'       => $iPostID,
                                   'sfloorname'   => $sFloorKey,
                                   'aroomname'    => $aRooms,
                                   'aroomtypes'   => $iRoomType, 
                                   ));
```